# C++ program using boost data structure and nghttp2 not compiling

Tags: c++, linux, boost, ubuntu-20.04

I have a http server that is created by using [nghttp2](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2). In this server I am trying to use boost's [`circular_buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) data structure.

Here is my C++ program which I am attempting to compile on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2;
using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2::server;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  boost::circular_buffer<request> buffer(3);
  
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  http2 server;

  server.handle("/", [&buffer](const request &req, const response &res) {
   
   buffer.push_back(req);
  });

  if (server.listen_and_serve(ec, "localhost", "3000")) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I compile this code with this command:

`g++ -std=c++14 server.cc -o server -lnghttp2_asio -lboost_system -lcrypto -lpthread -lssl -lboost_thread`

When I compile this I get the following error output

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from http-server.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; _Args = {const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&}; _Tp = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request]':
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:2:   required from 'static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; _Args = {const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&}; _Tp = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>]'
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:1427:59:   required from 'void boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::push_back_impl(ValT) [with ValT = const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&; T = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; Alloc = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>]'
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:1474:9:   required from 'void boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::push_back(boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type) [with T = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; Alloc = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type = const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::value_type = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request]'
http-server.cc:16:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: use of deleted function 'nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request::request(const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&)'
  145 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  146 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from http-server.cc:2:
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:39:7: note: 'nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request::request(const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   39 | class request {
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:39:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request_impl; _Dp = std::default_delete<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request_impl>]'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from /usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:28,
                 from http-server.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:414:7: note: declared here
  414 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:58,
                 from http-server.cc:3:
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::replace(boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::pointer, boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type) [with T = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; Alloc = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::pointer = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request*; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type = const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::value_type = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request]':
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:1423:13:   required from 'void boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::push_back_impl(ValT) [with ValT = const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&; T = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; Alloc = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>]'
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:1474:9:   required from 'void boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::push_back(boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type) [with T = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request; Alloc = std::allocator<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request>; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::param_value_type = const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&; boost::circular_buffer<T, Alloc>::value_type = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request]'
http-server.cc:16:24:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/circular_buffer/base.hpp:2413:14: error: use of deleted function 'nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request& nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request::operator=(const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&)'
 2413 |         *pos = item;
      |         ~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from http-server.cc:2:
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:39:7: note: 'nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request& nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request::operator=(const nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   39 | class request {
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:39:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request_impl; _Dp = std::default_delete<nghttp2::asio_http2::server::request_impl>]'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from /usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h:28,
                 from http-server.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:415:19: note: declared here
  415 |       unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: In the future, please include a question in your question. You neglected to indicate if you were merely asking for an explanation of why this error occurred, or if you were also interested in ways to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of that first error message is that `request(const request&)` (a.k.a. the copy constructor) is deleted. The `request` class is not copyable. The error message goes on to explain why `request` is not copyable, but this is tangential information unless you intend to modify the library you are using.

Since `request` is (implicitly) non-copyable, your lambda is not allowed to push a copy of its `req` parameter into a container (e.g., into a `boost::circular_buffer`, as you are attempting). You must come up with another approach.

In other cases, a solution might be to *move* instead of copy into the container. However, the callback signature specified by the library requires that the `req` parameter be a `const` reference, so moving from `req` is not allowed.

(One approach some people will wrongly attempt is to have the lambda store a pointer to the `req` parameter in the container. *Do not do this,* as there is no guarantee that the pointer will be valid once the current call to the lambda is complete.)

It appears that the intent is for `req` to be completely processed by the handler. One syntactically valid option is to extract the necessary data from `req` and store a copy of that data in a structure of your own definition. Whether or not this is advisable goes beyond the scope of a syntax question; it goes into the intended use of the nghttp2 library (something I am not familiar with).